# How to use VBA to click on button in webpage after you have logged in?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to click on a button on a webpage that I login to with VBA. I have already logged in and now I want to continue the process and click on another button. Here is what I have so far

```
Sub MyGmail()
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
MyURL = "https://www.programworkshop.com/6.0.0.0/login/login.aspx?skin=default&lang=enu"
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.Navigate MyURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True
Do
 Loop Until MyBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
   Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.Document
    HTMLDoc.all.Login.value = "something@something.com" 
    HTMLDoc.all.pass.value = "Password" 
    HTMLDoc.all.btnlogin.Click
```

This next line is where I hit a dead end

```
      HTMLDoc.all.sd5.Click
```

Here is the code from the website

```
<a id="sd5" class="nodeSel" href="javascript:treeAction(strURL5)" onmouseover="window.status='Examinees';return true;" onmouseout="window.status='';return true;" onclick="javascript: d.s(5);">Examinees</a>







Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Well for starters `Document` isn't declared, so you''re presumably going to get an error there.

Comment: Sorry I forget to fix that from me trying to play around with it. I fixed it now to what my original code was with the same problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "hit a dead end"? The first thing you need to do is get rid of `On Error GoTo Err_Clear`, because that's preventing Run-Time Errors which would tell you what the problem actually is (or at least provide hints).

Comment: Basically never use `On Error GoTo ... ` unless your destination actually *handles* the error (and you should also have a corresponding `On Error GoTo 0` so that the `GoTo ... ` is localized to trap very specific conditions). This one doesn't, it just pretends that there was no error and continues attempting to execute the next line of code, and so you probably have compounded errors causing subsequent errors, etc.

Comment: Okay I got rid of the 'On Error Goto' and it says 'Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support his property or method.

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Answer (score 0):

```
HTMLDoc.all.btnlogin.Click

While MyBrowser.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.Document
HTMLDoc.all.sd5.Click
```

Comment: It still didn't work. I tried running through it manually by pressing F8 and when I waited that didn't work either.